# Is it possible to post media to twitter using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, twitter

I can't find any clue about it except a deprecated article using tweetpic which is now closed.

Any alternative that works in Powershell ?

Update: my question is not about if there is a Twitter API of course I know there is, but as it is not trivial to use like this Powershell Guy who is stuck https://twittercommunity.com/t/media-upload-doesnt-work-powershell/93861 I'm looking for a module.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. [Twitter has an API for posting tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/overview); as such your question is about how to interact with an API, for which there are many articles and other questions. I think you'll have better luck posting a direct question about a specific coding problem if you're currently trying to do this and have run into an issue.

Comment: @briantist come one using an API is not trivial https://twittercommunity.com/t/media-upload-doesnt-work-powershell/93861 that's why one use powershell module.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I know already that's not my question as I said above.

Comment: @user310291 - Not trying to be pedantic about it but if two people respond in a similar way, the issue is with the question. I would close this one and post a new one rephrasing it to make sure it doesn't get interpreted wrong.

Comment: As written, this is either too broad or a request for a software recommendation, and in either case off-topic for [so].

Comment: @user310291 I understand; I didn't say it was trivial, but if you're asking for a library that is also not on-topic here. If you are trying to use the API and have a specific problem, I'm sure you'll be able to find help. I'm not saying that your question in general is a bad one or that you shouldn't ask it, it just doesn't fit the Q&A format _here_.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Not trying to be pedantic either but seems you just decide to be following the crowd.

Comment: @briantist seems it has become Kafka here, it wasn't like that in the past, good people must have been gone, only the ones who don't know the answer hide behind buraucratic comments ;)

Comment: @user310291 you are not alone in that feeling, and many are frustrated by both SO's narrow scope and especially its hostility to beginners. I agree that there are problems here, and I've sought to follow the guidelines in this case (because I agree with, not just because) while still being respectful. I'm sorry if I've not given you that impression. Clearly you don't agree with what is on-topic here and that's ok, so I will point you to a site that was created specifically as a reaction to the SO community; you may find people of similar mind there: https://www.askquestions.tech

Comment: @user310291 - fwiw, it was not my intention to get you fired up. I do believe a new question worded differently can attract people on SO that might be able to help you out. That's not kafka, that's just the way SO works. This question is burned. A new question attracts new people.

Comment: @briantist thanks for this site I didn't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Adam Bertram from https://www.adamtheautomator.com/twitter-module-powershell/.
**Disclaimer: this only allows to post tweets and DM.**

You can try using the PSM1 module below, but you need to create your own Twitter application on apps.twitter.com and generate an access token under the API keys section of the application. Once you do so, I recommend copying/pasting your API key, API secret, access token and access token secret as default parameters under the `Get-OAuthAuthorization` function.

```
<#  
    ===========================================================================
        Created on:     8/31/2014 3:11 PM
        Created by:     Adam Bertram
        Filename:       MyTwitter.psm1
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
===========================================================================
#>

function Get-OAuthAuthorization {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This function is used to setup all the appropriate security stuff needed to issue
        API calls against Twitter's API.  It has been tested with v1.1 of the API.  It currently
        includes support only for sending tweets from a single user account and to send DMs from
        a single user account.
    .EXAMPLE
        Get-OAuthAuthorization -DmMessage 'hello' -HttpEndPoint 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json' -Username adam
    
        This example gets the authorization string needed in the HTTP POST method to send a direct
        message with the text 'hello' to the user 'adam'.
    .EXAMPLE
        Get-OAuthAuthorization -TweetMessage 'hello' -HttpEndPoint 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'
    
        This example gets the authorization string needed in the HTTP POST method to send out a tweet.
    .PARAMETER HttpEndPoint
        This is the URI that you must use to issue calls to the API.
    .PARAMETER TweetMessage
        Use this parameter if you're sending a tweet.  This is the tweet's text.
    .PARAMETER DmMessage
        If you're sending a DM to someone, this is the DM's text.
    .PARAMETER Username
        If you're sending a DM to someone, this is the username you'll be sending to.
    .PARAMETER ApiKey
        The API key for the Twitter application you previously setup.
    .PARAMETER ApiSecret
        The API secret key for the Twitter application you previously setup.
    .PARAMETER AccessToken
        The access token that you generated within your Twitter application.
    .PARAMETER
        The access token secret that you generated within your Twitter application.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'None')]
    [OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$HttpEndPoint,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'NewTweet')]
        [string]$TweetMessage,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'DM')]
        [string]$DmMessage,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'DM')]
        [string]$Username,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$ApiKey = '2R3aJXohHmSABPaiQGaeprny7',
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$ApiSecret = '',
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$AccessToken = '',
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$AccessTokenSecret = ''
    )
    
    begin {
        $ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop
        Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
        try {
            [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security") | Out-Null
            [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net") | Out-Null
        } catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    
    process {
        try {
            ## Generate a random 32-byte string. I'm using the current time (in seconds) and appending 5 chars to the end to get to 32 bytes
            ## Base64 allows for an '=' but Twitter does not.  If this is found, replace it with some alphanumeric character
            $OauthNonce = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString())12345"))).Replace('=', 'g')
            Write-Verbose "Generated Oauth none string '$OauthNonce'"
            
            ## Find the total seconds since 1/1/1970 (epoch time)
            $EpochTimeNow = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)
            Write-Verbose "Generated epoch time '$EpochTimeNow'"
            $OauthTimestamp = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($EpochTimeNow.TotalSeconds).ToString();
            Write-Verbose "Generated Oauth timestamp '$OauthTimestamp'"
            
            ## Build the signature
            $SignatureBase = "$([System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($HttpEndPoint))&"
            $SignatureParams = @{
                'oauth_consumer_key' = $ApiKey;
                'oauth_nonce' = $OauthNonce;
                'oauth_signature_method' = 'HMAC-SHA1';
                'oauth_timestamp' = $OauthTimestamp;
                'oauth_token' = $AccessToken;
                'oauth_version' = '1.0';
            }
            if ($TweetMessage) {
                $SignatureParams.status = $TweetMessage
            } elseif ($DmMessage) {
                $SignatureParams.screen_name = $Username
                $SignatureParams.text = $DmMessage
            }
            
            ## Create a string called $SignatureBase that joins all URL encoded 'Key=Value' elements with a &
            ## Remove the URL encoded & at the end and prepend the necessary 'POST&' verb to the front
            $SignatureParams.GetEnumerator() | sort name | foreach { 
                Write-Verbose "Adding '$([System.Uri]::EscapeDataString(`"$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)&`"))' to signature string"
                $SignatureBase += [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)&".Replace(',','%2C').Replace('!','%21'))
            }
            $SignatureBase = $SignatureBase.TrimEnd('%26')
            $SignatureBase = 'POST&' + $SignatureBase
            Write-Verbose "Base signature generated '$SignatureBase'"
            
            ## Create the hashed string from the base signature
            $SignatureKey = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($ApiSecret) + "&" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($AccessTokenSecret);
            
            $hmacsha1 = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1;
            $hmacsha1.Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($SignatureKey);
            $OauthSignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hmacsha1.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($SignatureBase)));
            Write-Verbose "Using signature '$OauthSignature'"
            
            ## Build the authorization headers using most of the signature headers elements.  This is joining all of the 'Key=Value' elements again
            ## and only URL encoding the Values this time while including non-URL encoded double quotes around each value
            $AuthorizationParams = $SignatureParams
            $AuthorizationParams.Add('oauth_signature', $OauthSignature)
            
            ## Remove any API call-specific params from the authorization params
            $AuthorizationParams.Remove('status')
            $AuthorizationParams.Remove('text')
            $AuthorizationParams.Remove('screen_name')
            
            $AuthorizationString = 'OAuth '
            $AuthorizationParams.GetEnumerator() | sort name | foreach { $AuthorizationString += $_.Key + '="' + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Value) + '", ' }
            $AuthorizationString = $AuthorizationString.TrimEnd(', ')
            Write-Verbose "Using authorization string '$AuthorizationString'"
            
            $AuthorizationString
            
        } catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

function Send-Tweet {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This sends a tweet under a username.
    .EXAMPLE
        Send-Tweet -Message 'hello, world'
    
        This example will send a tweet with the text 'hello, world'.
    .PARAMETER Message
        The text of the tweet.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateLength(1, 140)]
        [string]$Message
    )
    
    process {
        $HttpEndPoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'
        
        $AuthorizationString = Get-OAuthAuthorization -TweetMessage $Message -HttpEndPoint $HttpEndPoint
        
        ## Convert the message to a Byte array
        #$Body = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("status=$Message");
        $Body = "status=$Message"
        Write-Verbose "Using POST body '$Body'"
        Invoke-RestMethod -URI $HttpEndPoint -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = $AuthorizationString } -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
}

function Send-TwitterDm {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This sends a DM to another Twitter user.  NOTE: You can only send up to 
        250 DMs in a 24 hour period.
    .EXAMPLE
        Send-TwitterDm -Message 'hello, Adam' -Username 'adam','bill'
    
        This sends a DM with the text 'hello, Adam' to the username 'adam' and 'bill'
    .PARAMETER Message
        The text of the DM.
    .PARAMETER Username
        The username(s) you'd like to send the DM to.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateLength(1, 140)]
        [string]$Message,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string[]]$Username
    )
    
    process {
        $HttpEndPoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json'
        
        ## Convert the message to a Byte array
        #$Message = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($Message)
        foreach ($User in $Username) {
            $AuthorizationString = Get-OAuthAuthorization -DmMessage $Message -HttpEndPoint $HttpEndPoint -Username $User -Verbose
            $User = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($User)
            $Body ="text=$Message&screen_name=$User"
            Write-Verbose "Using POST body '$Body'"
            Invoke-RestMethod -URI $HttpEndPoint -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = $AuthorizationString } -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember Send-Tweet
Export-ModuleMember Send-TwitterDm
```